# How to disable an optimization in LLVM

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang

I am compiling code with `clang` with -O4 optimization. However, I want to disable inlining of functions. I have my own LLVM pass that injects some code to the generated code. After my pass, I want to enable the inlining of functions. How can I do that.

Comment: Can't you just make sure that your pass is among the first optimisation passes? I.e. make sure that it's run *before* the function inliner pass?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use opt which [says](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/opt.html) it can run passes in any order.

```
clang -c main.cpp -O0 -emit-llvm | opt -load yourplugin -yourpass -inline
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are hacking clang, you can change passes order in file `clang/lib/CodeGen/BackendUtil.cpp`. You should insert your pass before inlining in method `CreatePasses()`.